# Query optimization diagram tool

Tags: optimization, visualization

What's the name of this kind of image used for showing query optimization? Are there tools that exist for drawing them?

[image]

Comment: This is just query in relational algebra notation. In sql it looks like `select customer-name from customer join account where balance <2500` What about optimization - i don't know

Comment: You can use programs like [draw.io](https://app.diagrams.net/) and [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/) to make them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name of that type of image /diagram  is

- **logical query plan (tree)**
- or **relational operator tree**
- , also  **relational algebra tree**.

Answer (score 0):

Boom!
There's something called the Relational Algebra Toolkit! http://rat.cs.panam.edu/RAT2/index.html

It's really cool and built for just what I wanted, learning and expressing Relational Algebra.